# dynamically changing the overflow property of a div causes its contents re-rendering (and SWF re-loading) on FireFox

Tags: firefox, flash, overflow, hidden, reload

I'm developing one of those annoying expanding ADS.

I have a SWF 600x600 px, inside a 250x300 px div with overflow=hidden.

When a click event inside the swf is fired, I call a JavaScript function that changes the div's overflow to visible, then the Swf should play an animation but it doesn't happen.
The SWF seems to have been re-loadedn because, if I click again, the div's overflow is already set to visible and the animation starts playing.
It only happens on FF.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Miss Spock

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Gecko, as you can follow the progress https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268